# Why is $\mathit X = \{x_n\} ⊂ ℝ^d, n = 1, . . . , N$ used to represent a sequence of audio frames?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, algorithms, signal-processing

I'm reading about audio processing but I'm not very well versed in the mathematical notation used in research papers. In this particular paper, $\mathit X = \{x_n\} ⊂ ℝ^d, n = 1, . . . , N$ represents a sequence of observations(frames/samples) from an audio signal.

“**Let $X = \{x_n\} ⊂ ℝ^d, n = 1, . . . , N$ be the observation sequence extracted from the audio signal, where n is a frame index.**
Let *L* be the number of past observations, we define a dynamic descriptor sequence
$Y = \{y_n\} ⊂ ℝ^α, n = L + 1, . . . , N$ as
$y_n = D(x_n−L, x_n−L+1, . . . , x_n)$
where *D* is a smoothing function that takes into account *L* observations and *α* is the new dimension after the transform.”

I understand that *X* is a SET of audio frames, with the sequence of frames beginning at 1 and ending at *N*.

What I don't understand is why *$\{x_n\}$* is written as a subset of the set of real numbers complement *d*. Not sure how to translate that intuitively. What's the implication for a set consisting of a series of audio frames?

> "*α* is the new dimension after the transform"

I can infer from this that *d* is also a dimension.

Comment: "written as a subset of the set of real numbers complement d" - $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the notation for the set of $d$-dimensional vectors. Does it make sense that a single audio frame could be represented as a $d$-dimensional vector? Also, a link to the paper may be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Anand yeah it makes sense that an audio frame can be represented as a d-dimensional vector. I didn't really know how to read that $ℝ^d$, definitely didn't know it was the notation for d-dimensional vectors. So this formula is basically saying that each audio frame in $\{X_n\}$ is a vector?

Comment: Yes, the notation is saying that each of the frames $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ is a $d$-dimensional vector, so the set of frames $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_N\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Thanks @Anand here's the paper if you're interested http://www2.eca.usp.br/mobile/portal/publicacoes/Pires_Queiroz_SMC_2011.pdf